# How to call a command with remapping in neovim?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, lua

Say I have a normal mode mapping on key `P`, for sure it can be executed in command mode:

```lua
:lua normal! P
```

Now I want to do this in lua, so I tried:

```lua
vim.cmd('normal! P')
```

and NeoVim executed it as "paste from clipboard", which caused some error since the buffer I'm working on is not modifiable. If I want it to execute what I have remapped on `P`, how?

**update**: I have tried removing the `!`, but it seems that it doesn't solve  the problem :/

Comment: Why do you need `:lua normal[!]`? Isn't just `:normal[!]` enough?

Comment: I have no idea, why you want to use `:lua` to execute a normal mode command. Also, please note, if the current buffer is not modifiable, an error will be expected. You should rather script something around it, to check whether the current buffer is modifiable (or readonly) or not and depending on the result perform the paste action

Comment: If you've already received an answer, please don't edit the question to ask a different question. (your original question didn't mention `vim.cmd` at all). It's not fair to the person that took the time to write up an answer for you,. Feel free to edit the question if you need to clarify it: otherwise you should create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

`:normal` runs normal mode commands. If the `!` is given, mappings will not be used. Without it when this command is called from a non-remappable mapping(:noremap), the argument can be mapped anyway.

So when mapping, don't use **`noremap`** and omit `!`.

### `:lua normal p`

Now will execute what you have remapped.

Comment: In lua there is a `vim.cmd()` that can execute `:lua ...`. And in this case I your answer would mean just removing the `!`. I did, and it still doesn't work. I have edited my question to be clear.

Comment: Did you also  disable ```noremap``` option ? With this option enabled,  mappings will not be used even if you remove ```!```.  I recorded some macro and mapped it to ```p``` .  With both ```!``` and ```noremap``` option enabled, it was still pasting with ```p```. But when I did this ```vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', 'p', '@q', {noremap=false})```, ```:lua normal p``` was doing whatever was recorded on ```q``` key.